How to find the spanning set of a subspace of particular dimension in terms of basis elements of vector space?
I am reading "Representations and Characters of Groups" by G James and M Liebeck.
Here, they attempt to find out the spanning set of a subspace of V $\equiv \mathbb R^{12}$.
So, there is a vector space V $\equiv \mathbb R^{12}$. It's basis elements are $v_{12}, v_{13}, v_{14}, v_{21}, v_{23}, v_{24}, v_{31}, v_{32}, v_{34}, v_{41}, v_{42}, v_{43}$.
The matrix corresponding to this is Original matrix with respect to basis of V.
Now, I reduced this using row echelon form to obtain the following
Reduced matrix 
In text the elements of spanning set are given as
$p_1 = (v_{23}-v_{32}) + (v_{34}-v_{43}) + (v_{42}-v_{24})$,
$p_2 = (v_{31}-v_{13}) + (v_{14}-v_{41}) + (v_{43}-v_{34})$,
$p_3 = (v_{12}-v_{21}) + (v_{41}-v_{14}) + (v_{42}-v_{24})$,
$p_4 = (v_{21}-v_{12}) + (v_{13}-v_{31}) + (v_{32}-v_{23})$.
From the reduced matrix, in each row we get the following
Row 1 - $(v_{12}-v_{21})$
Row 2 - $(v_{13}-v_{31})$,
Row 3 - $(v_{14}-v_{41}) $,
Row 4 - $(v_{23}-v_{32})$,
Row 5 - $(v_{24}-v_{42})$,
Row 6 - $(v_{34}-v_{434}) $.
Clearly, the spanning vectors mentioned in the text is a linear combination of these terms obtained from reduced matrix. I am unable to understand as to how they were obtained. What result or algorithm was used to do so?
Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.
